# Is there a way to log full URL with a router that only logs domain?

Tags: networking, router, logging

So my router can log domains and broadcast the log so I can read it and capture it.

But I would like to know if I can record the URLs and payload as well. Obviously; I can't do this with just the router. Is it possible to do something else? Maybe route the router traffic through my computer before going back out?

The idea is to capture what others are doing on my network.

I don't want to fork out the cash for a high-end router that can log properly.

This is using Windows 7 and my Router is a Netgear D6200 with the latest firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this, but I would suggest a proxy server. The one I would use is [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org). You install it on a Linux box (Raspberry Pi?) then configure your computer to use it. As well as insanely speeding up your connection you can configure it to log to a text file!

Answer (score 0):

No - it would be unusual for a provider of "home user" grade gear - and the specs say thats what this is - to provide the kind of complex routing you need to do. Because its a DSL router, you probably can't flash it with more advanced software (Like DD-WRT), which could help you to do this.

You don't need a high end router to do what you want.  What you need is a router which can run DD-WRT or similar - which means something like an Ethernet router - as well as an ADSL modem (you should be able to configure your current router to act as a modem).

Note that URLS are part of the payload -  URL logging opens a can of worms - and in order to log HTTPS URL requests from the browser you will either need to configure everything on the network to use it as an HTTPS proxy, or do a MITM attack - which means putting self-signed certificates on all the devices.     The same is true for monitoring any encrypted traffic.